# Countdown timer using System.Timers.Timer in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I need to show a countdown timer in label in a WPF application. My research have only led me to the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` - but since I use WPF I am not able to use it. `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` includes a `Tick` event, but `System.Timers.Timer` don't.

I need a countdown timer where I e.g can set a countdown of X minutes (X is larger than a couple of hundred minutes). A label will display the countdown values in the european standard format `HH:MM:SS`.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

A duplicate of this answer exists here: [How to make a wpf countdown timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748371/how-to-make-a-wpf-countdown-timer)

Comment: You can use `DispatcherTimer`

Comment: You can use the [DispatcherTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class as an alternative of `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`

Comment: is this what you are looking for [Dispatcher Timer] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748371/how-to-make-a-wpf-countdown-timer)